# How function the translation of language in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

EDIT:
How does google Chrome's "translate" feature know the original language of a page?

ORIGINAL QUESTION:
Please help i want to know how works the translation in Google Chrome when appear the translation menu in  upside of window, how know the browser in what language  it is the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess Google translate compare words from page text with words from its dictionaries. For example, if a page contains many german words, it's treated as a page in german language. Also, there are [a couple of ways](http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/a/aa043007.htm) to specify page language in HTML code of page. Google translate will use this settings if they're available on the page.

Comment: Thank you, but i need to know how work because i have a simple page but not appear the tool bar showing the translation.

Comment: Take a look on the link I've posted. Did you specify page language in your HTML code? Also check settings of your browser. Translation from some languages in the browser can be disabled by user.