# Error when trying to place folder in Resources/lang/en : Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have below code in my controller.

```
public function AllCountries() {
    $Countries = (new \App\DataAccess\CountryData())->GetAllCountries();
    app()->setLocale('fr');
    return view('Country.List')->with('Countries', $Countries->getData()->CountryList);
}
```

**Definition of method to fetch data is below.**

```
public function GetAllCountries() {
    return response()->json(['CountryList' => \App\Models\CountryModel::all()]);
}
```

**Below is the screenshot which shows Translation array**

[image]

**Below is the screenshot that shows the View called by Controller has just one word to show translation only.**

[image]

**When I run the application, I get following error.**

> Use of undefined constant CountriesList - assumed 'CountriesList'
>   (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MyAccount\resources\views\Country\List.blade.php)

Normally when we see websites which is not a default language set in our browser. We see a notification to translate the page on Page load. See the screenshot below.

[image]

But this does not come on my side. Although I can see French language but Translation notification is not coming. Why?

Comment: You mean you cut views/Country/List.blade.php to lang/en?

Comment: I am moving Country folder from View to Resources/lang/en

Comment: And there is still  views/Country/List.blade.php ? If that is so then I think the 404 you are getting is not connected with view or lang. I havent tried using capital letters on creating lang files. Maybe try using only lowercase letters. If you have lang/en/Country.php file then you can get it as trans("Country. <translation_keyword>")

Comment: Have you fixed your obvious syntax error? `{!! trans(CountriesList.CountryName) !!}` to `{!! trans("CountriesList.CountryName") !!}` (notice the quotations)?

Comment: Yes, But now another issue coming. Notification is not showing for translation as shown here: i.stack.imgur.com/fqPIV.png This is like one issue fixed and another coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read here for more about how localization works in Laravel:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/localization#introduction

If you really want to override the entire template, you can do this yourself:

```
$app->getLocale()
App::getLocale()
```

(but, I'm not suggesting this is usually a good idea - usually translating strings is a better idea.)

Those functions return the locale, so you can use this to fetch the appropriate view (e.g. placing all jp views inside a jp/ directory.)

You can use a ViewFactory's exists() method to check if it exists, and implement fallback logic as you like.  It might make a lot of sense to implement this on your own controller base class (which would inherit from the framework one), and have all your controllers subclass this new base class.  This way the logic can be shared.

Something roughly like this, for example:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesResources;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, AuthorizesResources, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    protected function localeViewResponse($view, $data = [], $mergeData = [])
    {
        $factory = view();
        $locale = app()->getLocale();

        if ($view->exists($locale . '.' . $view)) {
            return $view->make($locale . '.' . $view, $data, $mergeData);
        }

        return $view->make($view, $data, $mergeData);
    }
}
```

That being said, again, you should really consider if you have to do this.  Angad's method will make sense to other people familiar with Laravel, and is usually the better approach.  If you're having problems with 'undefined constant', make sure you're quoting things correctly and try updating your question with the code you've attempted.

Comment: Can you share some sample code on controller side? I am writing the code in controller to return view. In your link, i think it is using route file. I want to show default french language.

Comment: I've added an example.  You could also put this into a separate class and inject it into the controller's constructor, or etc.

Comment: I did the modification to make my question more clear. Please check now,

Comment: You'll notice in the documentation that the values should be quoted - e.g. `trans('messages.welcome')`.  `trans(CountriesList.CountryName)` is missing quotes.

Comment: Normally when we see websites which is not a default language set in our browser. We see a notification to translate the page on Page load. See the screenshot below.

http://i.stack.imgur.com/fqPIV.png

But this does not come on my side. Although I can see French language but Translation notification is not coming. Why?

Comment: That's really a separate question, but might be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691734/how-function-the-translation-of-language-in-google-chrome

Comment: I posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36851759/language-translation-popup-is-missing-on-dom-ready-in-browser-laravel-5-2 can u tell what's wrong in there?

Answer (score 0):

You are going about it incorrectly.

Laravel, like most other mvc frameworks, provides localization support out of the box: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/localization

So the following would be a better approach:

Create language files for the languages your application is offering ( for eg: english and french ).

```
resources
  | lang
    | en
      | countries.php
    | fr
      | countries.php
```

In each of the language files you would put the translations for variables appropriately:

```
// resources/lang/en/countries.php
return [
    'india' => "India"
];


// resources/lang/fr/countries.php
return [
    'india' => "Inde"
];
```

*Note: I dont know french I'm using google translate for this example*

Then in your view:

```
{{ trans('countries.india') }}
```

That will display the value from the appropriate language file depending on the application setting.

You can change the application language like so:

```
Route::get('countries/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale($locale);

    return view('countries.list');
});
```

Comment: I know I can't compare WordPress(CMS) with Laravel. In Wordpress, we could create a different page for English and a different page for another language. So there is no need to create one file for translation and another file for view to get translation. Is there any better way to implement translation ? may be something like Wordpress?

Comment: @Helper In my opinion, this method makes it easier to maintain and expand localization. Surely you see the advantage of using this over how wordpress does it.

Comment: @Helper You mention in wordpress you have to create 1 view per language. Isnt it better to create 1 language file per language and only have 1 view?

Comment: IN Wordpress there will be total 2 files if there are 2 languages. In Laravel. there will be 3 files. 1 View files and 2 files for languages.

Comment: When I implemented above it says : `Use of undefined constant countries - assumed 'countries'`